# Как полностью заполнить Toobar?

Tags: android, toolbar

Добрый день. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как полностью заполнить Toolbar: слева впритык кнопка меню, справа впритык квадратная иконка с такими же размерами, а между ними заголовок. 
Не могу понять, откуда слева остаётся место.

[image: Непонятность]

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_height="59dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorTopBarMenu"
app:theme="@style/OrangeAppTheme"
app:popupTheme="@style/OrangeAppTheme">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="59dp">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="59dp"
        android:layout_height="59dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/icon_menu"
        android:id="@+id/button2" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/main_titale"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="17sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы хотите сильно кастомизировать тулбар - то он вам не нужен. Просто уберите его и делайте его подобие через обычную разметку. Суть тулбара - простое создание стандартного компонента. Если у вас что-то не стандартное - он вам не нужен

Comment: Окей, спасибо=)